# How to use gorm cascade update with Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, spring-orm

**Relationship between my domains :**

```
class Cartridge
{ ...
  static hasMany = [cartridgeLanes: CartridgeLane]
  static belongsTo = [request:Request]
}

class CartridgeLane 
{...
  CartridgeLaneSampleAttributes cartridgeLaneSampleAttributes
  static belongsTo = [cartridge:Cartridge]
}

class CartridgeLaneSampleAttributes
{...
  static belongsTo = CartridgeLane
}
```

**Code for cascade update :**

```
  def sampleAttributes = new CartridgeLaneSampleAttributes()
        sampleAttributes.sampleId = sample.get("ID")
        ...

  def cartridgeLane = new CartridgeLane()
        cartridgeLane.laneId = lane.get("ID") as Integer
        ...
        cartridgeLane.cartridgeLaneSampleAttributes = sampleAttributes

  def cartridge = Cartridge.findByCartridgeID(cartridgeId)
  cartridge.addToCartridgeLanes(cartridgeLane)
  cartridge.save()
```

First, I'm linking **sampleAttributes** with **cartridgeLane**, then I'm finding the **cartridge** I want to update (linking to **cartridgeLane**), and finally I'm saving.

This code only **INSERT** data (eg : add sampleAttributes and cartridgeLane data to cartridge).
My problem is I'm looking for an **UPDATE** (not an INSERT).

How can I manage cascading update ?
How gorm differentiate an update from an insert ?
Is there a more efficient way for cascading update ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you're calling your update method/closure you may be able to leverage [Grails data binding](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html).

As an aside, your domain model may be obfuscating the logic in your application. Hard to see without more detail, but it looks like you're trying to have dynamically bound attributes to a domain class using a Map or something. This type of manipulation will require you to write a lot of the logic yourself, and complicate your model. You may want to reconsider the design.

Answer (score 0):

This cascading update works :

```
def cartridge = Cartridge.findByCartridgeID(cartridgeId).id as Long
def cartridgeLane = CartridgeLane.findCartridgeLanesByCartridge(cartridge).findByLaneId(laneId)  

// Update cartridgeLane domain
cartridgeLane.laneId = lane.get("ID") as Integer
...

// update cartridgeLaneSampleAttributes domain
cartridgeLane.cartridgeLaneSampleAttributes.sampleId = sample.get("ID")
...

cartridgeLane.save()
```